# absolute div positioning

Tags: css

The problem is that `.calendar` div is staying on top of the page and I want it to move when the page is scrolled.

```
.calender{
    position:absolute;
    top:250px;
    left:600px;
    width:200px;
}   
.popup{
    width:980px;
    overflow:auto;
    height:500px;   
}


<div class="calender"></div>
<div class="popup">
    <input type="text" value="">
    <input type="text" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: maybe try `fixed` rather than `absolute`

Comment: Look at my answer, but this is one alternative that might interest [<input type="date"](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_date)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are using as a calendar, but this should help you to start..

The `position: absolute;` always reffers to the parent `position: relative;` if you don't have any it will use `<html>` as relative, that is why it was not going down when you scroll.

What I did is add a `position: relative;` container to hold the calendar allways next to the textbox even if you scroll.

[Here is a page about CSS positioning](http://cssreset.com/understanding-css-relative-and-absolute-positioning-explained/), you should read it, it is very important..

```css
.container{
  position: relative;
}
.calender{
width:200px;
}   
.popup{
position:absolute;
top:20px;
left:0;
width:980px;
overflow:auto;
height:500px;   
}
```

```html
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div class="container">
  <input class="calender" type="text" value="sdsds">
  <div class="popup">
  <div style="width: 40px; height:40px; background-color:red;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
```

**EDIT:** I read your question again, and I understood that you need it in the same place even if you scroll, I'm not sure if this is the expected behaviour, but here is another sample and a little explanation..

`position: fixed;` allways reffers to the browser window as the parent any parent `position: relative;` won't influentiate on it's positioning..

```css
.container{
  position: relative;
}
.calender{
width:200px;
}   
.popup{
position:fixed;
top: 100px;
left: 8px;
width:980px;
overflow:auto;
height:500px;   
}
```

```html
<br /><br /><br /><br />
<div class="container">
  <input class="calender" type="text" value="sdsds">
  <div class="popup">
  <div style="width: 40px; height:40px; background-color:red;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code ... I changed the position to fixed and changed the div to appear

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style media="screen">
    .calender {
      position: fixed;
      top: 250px;
      left: 600px;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: red;
    }
    .popup {
      width: 980px;
      overflow: auto;
      height: 500px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>



  <div class="calender"></div>
  <div class="popup">
    <input type="text" value="">
    <input type="text" value="">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```